# Apache & Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, веб-сервер

Здравствуйте!
Вот часто слышу, что веб-сервер NGINX куда быстрее Apache`a, но тем не менее апач используется почти в 60% современных сайтах. Так вот интересно, почему выбор остается за апачем, если nginx способен выдержать куда более сильные нагрузки? И есть ли существенная разнича между этими двумя решениями? Спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Есть ли существенная разнича между этими двумя решениями?"

Есть и заключается она, в первую очередь в том, что apache работает по принципу - новый запрос = новый поток, nginx работает с использованием событийной модели, соответственно новый запрос не порождает новых потоков. Apache настолько распространен потому, что популярен (тоже самое, например, с виндой).

Довольно часто Apache используется как бэк-енд сервер. Т.е. nginx занимается выдачей статики и проксированием остальных запросов на Apache. Если есть возможность отказаться от Apache вообще, ИМХО, так и стоит поступить.

Да и вообще, в проектах адекватных масштабов практически со 100% вероятностью фронт-енд сервером стоит nginx, неважно сервер написан на C++, java или на php, node.js.

---

"есть ли существенная разнича между этими двумя решениями"

Вообщем в основном разница в подходе:

```
 запрос -> поток
 // vs
 запрос -> событие
```

PS: возможно вам будет интересно [это](http://ru.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_PHP_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5_nginx)

Answer (score 6):

Говорить о полной замене apache'а nginx'ом, все равно что говорить о полной замене бомбардировщиков истребителями: вроде как, летать умеют оба, но последние это делают быстрее.

Apache и nginx - это два *совершенно* разных продукта, которые лишь частично пресекаются в целевых нишах, по этому никогда один полностью не заменит другого. А про их функциональные отличия уже написано [множество статей](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F%20apache%20%D0%B8%20nginx).

Answer (score 2):

Это вопрос из разряда: "Почему пользуются Виндой, когда Линукс её превосходит?" Наверно вопрос риторический. Популярность, которая хорошо проработана промоутерами.

Comment: Винда, кстати, куда лучше =)

Comment: Это чем же? Тем что под неё предусмотрительно наплодили софта? Или то что она не дает скучать, когда ты за вирусами охотишся в то время, когда под Линуху как-то с вирусами не сложилось?

Comment: Винда мультифункциональна, линуксы же ограничены своим дистрибутивом.

Comment: Это дело наживное. Винду за бабло нам загоняют, вот у них и деньги есть на неограниченные разработки.

А взять эту (тут мат) вечную проблему с дровами, определением железа у винды. А Линукс любое железо и периферию, как родных принимает

Comment: Честно, с линуксами работаю довольно мало, поэтому всех прелестей этой системы не знаю...

Comment: @Dex, не правильная у вас ссылка. Правильная [вот](http://ithappens.ru/story/8886).

PS Даже цитату приведу, дабы акцентировать внимание.

> Вы серьёзно не понимаете, что красноглазие совершенно не связано с типом операционки? Что для профессиональной работы (поясняю: это когда тебе платят деньги за то, чтобы подведомственная система работала всегда, когда ей положено это делать, и ты это обеспечиваешь, а когда система вдруг не работает — наступает ой, и денег не платят) нужно любую систему знать сверху донизу? В этом смысле ни одна система не проще и не лучше другой.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, ага, она самая! Торопился.

Что значит "дистрибутивами, которые ограничены"? Вы оба спорите о вещах, в которых слабо разбираетесь, судя по вашим сообщениям. Лучше не нужно

Comment: Холиварить так холиварить =)Винда платная, что означает полноценный саппорт со стороны разработчика. Линукс условно-бесплатный (в зависимости от дистрибутива), т.е. если что-то сломалось или не знаешь как настроить, то ищешь ответ сам. На работе когда перешли Win Server 2012, поставили домен (domain controller - так вроде правильно), я, как разработчик, тоже раньше сопротивлялся и не понимал преимуществ. Теперь понимаю - все стало как то более централизованно, стало проще бекапить, админам стало проще обновлять групповые политики, да и просто софт на компах, потому что все стало с одного руля

Comment: Сколько админов знаю - кого ни спрашивал, всем предпочтительнее админить винду. Все говорят, что если у работодателя нет денег, то тогда приходится иметь дело с линуксом. Да и разработчики под .net стоят дороже среднерыночной цены.