# Сервер Nginx CGI

Tags: nginx, cgi

Друзья не судите строго за вопрос  .Можете объяснить работу  `cgi` с сервером  Nginx. При работе над одним проектом увидел такую форму отправки

```
<form id="contectform"  action="script.cgi"  method="post">

        <input type="text" name="name" placehold="name" />
           <button type="submit" value="send">Send</button>
</form>
```

Можете подсказать почему обработка данных ссылается на `script.cgi` а не `index.php` . Скажу что сайт работал на Nginx. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Apache & Nginx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/97401/apache-nginx)

Comment: Про  CGI  несказанно

Comment: Давайте рассуждать логически. При подобных данных формы, форма будет отправляться на адрес  http(s)://yourdomain.yourdomain/folder_where_form_live/script.cgi
По сути `script.cgi` в этом ни коим образом не говорит вам что протокол взаимодействия веб сервера и собственно приложения. 
Nginx будет обрабатывать этот запрос в соответствии с настройками, в частности найдет нужный location и с правилами в этом location отправит куда нужно. 
Еще короче, похоже - cgi тут вообще не причем, более того в современном мире уже давно используют fast-cgi, а товарищ просто так захотел...

Comment: Адрес не значит абсолютно ничего. На сервере этот script.cgi может обрабатываться как угодно чем угодно. Можно и наоборот, какой-нибудь адрес типа index.php обрабатывать nodejs-сервером например

Answer (score 2):

> почему обработка данных ссылается на script.cgi а не index.php?

потому что разработчиком сайта так задумано: чтобы при нажатии пользователем на кнопку с надписью `send` его [http-клиент](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B) отправлял [post-запрос](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) с [url-ом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

```
схема://адрес/путь/script.cgi
```

а не

```
схема://адрес/путь/index.php
```

p.s. уж как [http-сервер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80), доступный по указанному адресу, будет обрабатывать данный запрос (и сможет ли вообще обработать), целиком и полностью зависит от возможностей/настроек/конфигурации этого самого сервера.